# Загрузка сайта с локального на хостинг

Tags: opencart

Добрый день!

Не могу понять, почему не подгружаются основные скрипты на хостинг. (Cам сайт на хостинг залит,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но не подгружаются основные скрипты, всплывающие окна, форма заказа и т. д.).

На локальном хостинге всё работает и подгружается.

[**Сам сайт**](http://culikdima2.temp.swtest.ru). Через панель разработчика можно увидеть ошибки, вот только их нет в локальной версии. Как это возможно? 
Можете помочь, уже 2 день мучаюсь. Прикрепляю файлы со скринами на локальном и на хостинге.

Магазин на системе OpenCart, последняя версия.

Ошибки:

```
1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  - equalheights.js

2) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  - mfp-zoom-in.css

3) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  - equalheights.js

4) Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css(...).equalHeights is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (theme.js:38)
    at j (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)                 -  theme.js:38

5) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  -  mfp-zoom-in.css
```

Comment: лучше не снимки экрана приводить, а текст ошибок. в виде текста, а не картинки, естественно.

Comment: 1)Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - equalheights.js
2)Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - mfp-zoom-in.css
3)Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css(...).equalHeights is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (theme.js:38)
    at j (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)

Comment: внесите эту информацию в текст вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: Если 404 то думаю проблема в путях.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине видно, что файл не подгрузился. Данный файл ищется по этому пути:

> culikdima2.temp.swtest.ru/catalog/view/theme/apple/stylesheet/catalog/view/theme/apple/stylesheet/mfp-zoom-in.css

Очевидно, что путь  `catalog/view/theme/apple/stylesheet` в урле дублируется, что и вызывает ошибку. Проверьте как формируются урлы к скриптам.